# How can I restrict elasticsearch from inserting the document within index which has fields which are not part of current mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I have been inserting documents within my index for which I already defined a mapping in following way :

```
PUT /users
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "desc": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to insert a document within the index with additional fields such as :

```
PUT users/_doc/1
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "desc": "Identity Unknown",
  "location": "Neverland"
}
```

It modifies my defined mapping to :

```
{
    "properties": {
        "desc": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "standard"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can restrict this directly via es or do I need to add condition within my scripts to handle this behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into documentation more thoroughly I found a way to do it through elasticsearch itself. We can update mapping and provide `dynamic` field/property as `false` or `strict`.

1. `false` -> indexing field will get ignored and won't affect the mapping.
2. `strict` -> indexing field throws error with 400 status of Bad Request

For me I wanted the inserting to throw an error so I chose `strict` option which is working for me as expected :

```
PUT /users/_mapping
{
  "dynamic": "strict"
}
```